# Setting up Docker on Windows for PHP - can not find config file

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I installed [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) and trying to pull some images from a private server. It asks to `--insecure-registry` to the config file but can not find it.

Has anyone encountered the same issue and is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this a little bit confusing in boot2docker.

You need to set those arguments on the daemon, not the client. In boot2docker that means you need to ssh into the VM and edit a config file. You can ssh into the VM by running `boot2docker ssh`. Then edit the file `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` (which may not exist) to include the line:

```
EXTRA_ARGS="--insecure-registry=MY_PRIVATE_SERVER"
```

Where `MY_PRIVATE_SERVER` is the address of your registry. You'll then need to restart boot2docker (e.g. `boot2docker restart`).

You can find more details at https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md under local customisation.